# How to use parameters in TpFIBDataSet SQL query?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, fibplus

I am using FIBPlus library and Delphi 10.3 Rio.

Inside my project I have TpFIBDataSet component.

Under SQL Generator I defined SQL Select with 'where clause' and inside 'where clause' I have one parameter.

[My SQL Select and parameter called ':BROJ'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFXdo.png)

How can I use that parameter in my code, and how can I pass value into that parameter?

Comment: Show your problem with a [mcve].

Comment: Add the code and the query you are using, the current form of your question will not lead to an exact solution.

Comment: Your question is a bit misleading. Until I had read the question, I thought you meant parameters to an Object Pascal function. But you mean parameters to some SQL query or some such. And it is terribly vague. People will need more information, especially: what have you tried already? Give us the code.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis:  Yes, he meant a SQL parameter, or i'm a Dutchman.

Comment: Yes i meant SQL parameter.

Comment: @MartynA: You wish you were.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis:  <g>.  Not quite sure how to take that!

Comment: Everyone wishes they were. And if not, that's just because they don't know how great it is. <g>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a copy of the TpFIBDataSet handy. but usually you set a dataset parameter by code like this:

```
MyDataSet.Parameters.ParamByName('BROJ').AsString := 'some value';
```

Note : With some TDataSet descendants, the parameters collection is named `Params` rather than `Parameters`.

I gather from your suggested edit that with the dataset type you are using, you can write this instead:

```
MyDataSet.ParamByName('BROJ').AsString := 'some value';
```

Comment: I did some changes and now its working perfectly. U gave me huge clue! Thank you so much!